# problems with using string.join() operator

Tags: python

I tested out the `string.join()` method on a few lines of code:

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 0

superpower = []

if a == 1:
        superpower.append("flying")
if b == 1:
        superpower.append("soaring")
if c == 1:
        superpower.append("high")

", ".join(superpower)

print superpower
```

but the result always comes back as just a regular list, not a string. How can I fix this? I'm new to python, and would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5):

`", ".join(superpower)` *returns* a string, it doesn't convert the input iterable into a string.  You aren't doing anything with that return value:

```
superpower_str = ', '.join(superpower)
print(superpower_str)
```

is probably what you want.